# Executing same command for several files in same repository in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I'd like to execute the following command for several files in same repository in linux:

```
../../../../../openSMILE-2.1.0/SMILExtract -C ../../../../../openSMILE-2.1.0/config/IS13_ComParE.conf -I inputfilename.wav -D outputfilename.csv
```

there are several files (named 1.wav, 2.wav, 3.wav) in the directory and if I execute

```
../../../../../openSMILE-2.1.0/SMILExtract -C ../../../../../openSMILE-2.1.0/config/IS13_ComParE.conf -nologfile 1 -noconsoleoutput 1 -I 1.wav -D 1.csv
```

it outputs 1.csv.

How can I create 1.csv, 2.csv, 3.csv, .. by executing just one single command in linux? (or do I have to make .sh file?)

Comment: What shell are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably cleaner to put the following to a script, but you can type it directly into the bash command line as well:

```
#! /bin/bash
for file in *.wav ; do
    prefix=${file%.wav}  # Remove from the right.
    ../../../../../openSMILE-2.1.0/SMILExtract \
        -C ../../../../../openSMILE-2.1.0/config/IS13_ComParE.conf \
        -I "$file" -D "$prefix".csv
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much bro! You are great guy

Comment: It's like the concept of what I type and this stuff that goes in these mysterious scripts is a bridge too far... (I'll give you the upvote if the OP won't)